# How to running dd command in python for windows

Tags: python

[Solved]
I found the method finally..., I've updated the solution here, hope it can helps someone who need.

Download the dd file for windows first, http://www.chrysocome.net/dd, after unzip, put the dd.exe into python scripts file, then, it's works!!

---

I would like to excute dd command in python but it doesn't works, the error is "'dd' is not recognized as an internal or external command", but it's works in cmd on windows.
I was try but cann't find similar module or function, could anyone help me? Thanks!

Below is my code.

```
def dd_cmd():
   ddfile = open('dd_test.txt','w')
   ddcmd = ["dd", "if=d:/tartest/config-5w20.txt", "of=d:/tartest/config-5w20a.txt", "bs=1", "count=36", "status=progress"] 
   d = subprocess.Popen(ddcmd,stdout=ddfile, stderr=ddfile)
   d.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   dd_cmd()
```

Comment: From your pathnames it looks like you're on Windows. AFAIK there is no standard dd command on Windows

Comment: Yes...I would like to write a dd command scripts on Windows not on Linux, so is there no any methods to resolve? lol

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python

Comment: You can surely copy the first 36 bytes of one file to a new one in 3 lines or fewer of Python.

Comment: Just to reiterate, you don't need an external utility to copy bytes from one file to another. In very brief, `with open(file1, "rb") as inp, open(file2, "wb") as outp: outp.write(inp.read(36))`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There isn't any official `dd` command for Windows. You can use an [alternative](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd).
Download it first, then run your code easily.

---

**Hint**

You should put the executable file next to other files of your project
Or
Put the executable file anywhere you want and update Path Environment

Comment: Yes, for the Windows version was installed, and I excute in cmd it's works, so I think it's maybe can running in python...

Comment: Where did you put the `dd` executable file? @Althea

Comment: It's solved finally!! I've updated the content above, you can see it. Thanks for help. :)